# How can I attempt to read bad sectors from the end of the disk, using ddrescue?

Tags: data-recovery, ddrescue, bad-blocks, dynamic-disk

How can I attempt to read bad sectors from the end of the disk, using `ddrescue`? I have dynamic volumes and the LDR is kept at the end of the disk, unlike MBR.

I remember that I've tried `--reverse` but it changed the direction from the last tried position (basically going back towards the starting point, from the first bad sectors found), instead of starting from the end of the disk.

This is the output of `head -n 10 mapfile`:

```
# Rescue Logfile. Created by GNU ddrescue version 1.16
# Command line: ddrescue -d -f -r3 /dev/sdb /dev/sda rescue.log
# current_pos  current_status
0x4E39922200   /
# pos       size        status
0x00000000  0x1DF9F200  +
0x1DF9F200  0x00001E00  -
0x1DFA1000  0x45EE0200  +
0x63E81200  0x00000E00  -
0x63E82000  0x00000200  +
```

Comment: Please post the beginning of your current map file: `head -n 10 mapfile`. `--reverse` reverses the direction but I don't expect it to necessarily alter `current_pos`, especially when the tool performs something other than "copying non-tried blocks". Changing `current_pos` manually shouldn't break things but I haven't tested this (therefore just a comment).

Comment: `# Rescue Logfile. Created by GNU ddrescue version 1.16
# Command line: ddrescue -d -f -r3 /dev/sdb /dev/sda rescue.log
# current_pos  current_status
0x4E39922200     /
#      pos        size  status
0x00000000  0x1DF9F200  +
0x1DF9F200  0x00001E00  -
0x1DFA1000  0x45EE0200  +
0x63E81200  0x00000E00  -
0x63E82000  0x00000200  +`

Comment: Thank you. Hint: next time add relevant information to the *question*; your comment is barely readable. Even if it was very clear, the general rule is any question should be self contained and complete, it should not rely on following comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>Preliminary note: your version of `ddrescue` is `1.16`, it's old, released on 2012-06-11. This answer is based on the documentation of the version `1.24`.</sub>

---

These are options you can use to make `ddrescue` read a particular fragment of the input device or file:

> `-i bytes`
> `--input-position=bytes`
> Starting position of the rescue domain in `infile`, in bytes. Defaults to `0`. […]
>
> `-s bytes`
> `--size=bytes`
> Maximum size of the rescue domain in bytes. It limits the amount of input data to be copied. […]

[<sup>source</sup>](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html#Invoking-ddrescue)

In your case you should specify `-i bytes`, so the structure you care for is between `bytes` and the end of the disk. Note `ddrescue` accepts e.g. `200G` or `200Gi` (and these are different positions).

> Numbers given as arguments to options (positions, sizes, rates, etc) may be expressed as decimal, hexadecimal or octal values (using the same syntax as integer constants in C++), and may be followed by a multiplier and an optional `B` for "byte". […]

See the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html#Invoking-ddrescue), there's a table of possible unit multipliers. According to [another part of the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html#Mapfile-structure) hexadecimal (`0x…`) numbers in a mapfile indicate positions and sizes in bytes, so you can use them in the same form. E.g. to cover only this part of your mapfile

```
0x1DF9F200  0x00001E00  -
```

the command should use `-i 0x1DF9F200 -s 0x00001E00`.

You can use `-i` and/or `-s` with the mapfile `ddrescue` created so far, the existing information should not be lost. Similarly you can run the tool later without these options and its scope (rescue domain) will be the entire device again.

Comment: Am I allowed to say something like this? `ddrescue -d -f -r3 -s 0x00000200 -i 0x63E82000 /dev/sdb /dev/sda rescue.log`

Comment: @Nick I believe so, answer expanded. But please note your version of `ddrescue` is old.